# Design Pattern reference implementations in Ada?

Tags: design-patterns, ada

Does anyone know of some good reference implementations of common design patterns in Ada?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several articles about "[Software Patterns Implemented in Ada](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Patterns&Title=Patterns)".

Comment: Seems that adapower is down. Is there any other source in the Internet?